# Retrieving data from 2 tables in SQLite (android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am creating a fitness app and have 2 sqlite database tables (TABLE_CARDIO & TABLE_WEIGHTS) in which workout info can be saved to. I need to create a query to fetch all data from both of these tables. At the moment I have a query which works and fetched all data from TABLE_CARDIO as shown below:

```
public Cursor getWorkoutData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from "+TABLE_CARDIO,null);
    return result;
}
```

However I need to modify this query so that it can fetch the data from TABLE_WEIGHTS too. I know there are other questions on here about fetching data from 2 tables however, I have failed to understand how to apply a solution to my specific scenario. I thought adding '+TABLE_WEIGHTS,null' after '+TABLE_CARDIO,null' would work but it doesn't. Any help appreciated!

Comment: What are the structures of these table and what you want to retrieve? Please be specific a little.

Answer (score 0):

with SQL you can embed multiple select statements into the same query.  for instance,

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT *
    FROM   TABLE_CARDIO
    ),
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_WEIGHTS
    )
)
```

You can also use Unions,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_CARDIO UNION SELECT * FROM TABLE_WEIGHTS
```

Of course you are getting all of the data here in one return statement.

So your java string should contain both statements inside of the argument

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARDIO + " UNION SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_WEIGHTS
```

rather then

```
select * from table_1, null, select * from table_2, null.
```

Comment: Hi @Abeltensor , thanks for the response! I tried `"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARDIO + " UNION SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_WEIGHTS ` however it throws the error: Cannot resolve method 'rawQuery(java.lang.String)'

Comment: You may have to convert the query to string; for instance 



     `cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARDIO + " 
     UNION SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_WEIGHTS, 
                     new String[]{ searchText.getText().toString() + "%" });`